# text background highlighting is not visible in current line

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt application, I use `QPlainTextEdit` widget with a text/syntax highlighter (similar to this one https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html) which highlights certain keywords by changing the background of the keywords present in the text. It works perfect.

But I also use highlighting of the current line as described here https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/widgets-codeeditor.html Specifically this method:

```
void CodeEditor::highlightCurrentLine()
{
     QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections;

     if (!isReadOnly()) {
         QTextEdit::ExtraSelection selection;

         QColor lineColor = QColor(Qt::yellow).lighter(160);

         selection.format.setBackground(lineColor);
         selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat::FullWidthSelection, true);
         selection.cursor = textCursor();
         selection.cursor.clearSelection();
         extraSelections.append(selection);
     }

     setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
}
```

It also works fine. Except... it does not work well in combination with the syntax highlighter. The background set by the current line always takes precedence over the highlighting by syntax highlighter. Which means that the keywords are not highlighted in the current line.

I would like the syntax highlighting to take precedence over the current line highlighting. So that they keywords are highlighted also in the current line. Is there anything I can do about this?

Of course, I could highlight the keywords by changing the foreground instead of background, which would solve the issue. The problem is that in my usecase highlighting by changing background color looks better on the eye.

Comment: Your links for the Qt docs are all for Qt4. Are you really using Qt4? [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html) are the Qt5 versions.

Comment: I am using Qt5. The code in your links is the same as in mine.